# PHP - Creating an array of new objects

Tags: php

I want to create an array of **new** objects

Example:

```
$updateVariantForms = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($this->variants); $i++) {
            $updateVariantForms[] = new UpdateVariantForm();
        }
```

Is there an easier or more straight forward way to create an array of those new objects?

Comment: Nothing really wrong with this, unless sizeof is expensive.  You might want to calculate that upfront, rather than on each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much different:

```
<?php
class Foo
{}

foreach(range(1,10) as $i)
    $foos[] = new Foo;
```

Slightly terser:

```
$i = 0;
while($i++<10)
    $foos[] = new Foo;
```

This won't work because of references, all the same Foos:

```
$foos = array_pad([], 10, new Foo);
```

Comment: I like the while one. Its a bit cleaner than mine. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Please note that `range()` creates an array. Depending on the size we're talking about it can be an issue or not.